# IoU when labels are different

Tags: object-detection, mean

The IoU focuses only on the bounding boxes.
My predictions for one Image are (Yolo) e.g.

| label | x | y | w | h |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.3 |
| 1 | 0.9 | 0.9 | 0.05 | 0.05 |

And my ground truth is:

| label | x | y | w | h |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.3 |
| 1 | 0.9 | 0.9 | 0.05 | 0.05 |

Now I have the question of how to calculate the IoU.

Do I check Prediction 1 (P1) with Ground-Truth (G1) and G2. and P2 with G1 and G2 and if I have an IoU of 0 do I reject the result?

So once how do I find out if the box I am checking for is the correct one and what do I do if the labels don't match?